# Error while passing data from a child to parent component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

As soon as ObjectRow's onchange1 and onchange2 are triggered, it gives a runtime error of sendColor is not a function(same for sendName) . As my form submit button is present in the parent component of ObjectRow, I am trying to get the data of ObjectRow's input in my parent component so as to proceed further. Is it the right way to do so or any other method better?

```
     const rows = []
            for (let i = 0; i < rewards; i++) {
        
                rows.push(<ObjectRow key={i} num={i} sendColor={sendColor} sendName={sendName} />);
                console.log(angle)
            }
     

    const sendColor = (data) => {
                console.log(data)
            }
        
            const sendName = (data) => {
                console.log(data)
            }




  <form onSubmit={onsubmit}>
            {rows}
        <div className='flex justify-center'> 
<button className={`${rewards > 0 ? 'bg-red-700 w-4/12 rounded-md  p-2 font-normal text-lg text-white' : 'hidden'}`}>Submit</button>
</div> 
</form>
```

Below is the Objectrow component:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import {useState} from 'react'
    
    function ObjectRow({num,sendColor,sendName}) { 
    
        
      const [name, setName] = useState('')
      const [color,setColor]=useState('')
       
      
        
      const handlechange1=(e)=>{
          
            setColor(e.target.value)
            sendColor(color)
        }
    
      const handlechange2 = (e) => {
    
         setName(e.target.value)
          sendName(name)
      }
    
       
      
       
      
    
       
      return (
       <>
    <div className='text-xl font-semibold text-violet-700'>Reward{num+1}</div>
                 
                  <label>Reward Name</label>
                  <input type='text'
                  name="rewardName" 
                    onChange={handlechange2}
                    value={name} 
                   className='bg-slate-400 my-4  mx-2'>
                    </input>                                  
            
             
                  <label>Reward Color</label>
                  <input type='text' 
                  name="rewardColor"
                 onChange={handlechange1} 
                   value={color}
                   className='bg-slate-400 my-4  mx-2'>
                  </input>              
              
               
              <hr /> 
       </>
      )
    }
    
    export default ObjectRow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining sendColor and sendName above your declaration of rows

Comment: thanks, that was a very sily mistake of me